# Stable connectivity in a high-density residential WiFi environment?

Tags: wireless

I live in a densely populated area and my devices see 10-20 wifi networks at any given time. Once in every few minutes a ping to my router goes up to the point of timeout and the device loses the connection to the wifi. I believe that it has something to do with too many networks being in the range and the router can't keep up, but I am not exactly sure that this is the root cause. I tried all usual advices, like to play with channels and nothing helps. I have 2 networks on the same router, 2.4 ghz and 5 ghz, and 2.4 one is performing worse. I forgot what the exact router is, it is TP-Link, an older model from [this line](https://www.tp-link.com/au/home-networking/dsl-modem-router/td-w9977/) (I am not using ADSL part). I am 100% sure that the wireless part is the culprit, it works perfectly fine via an Ethernet cable.

Based on this I have two questions:

1. Are connection issues related to too many wifis? How can I verify or disprove it?
2. If it is about wifis, how can I fix it? Will buying a better/newer router help?

Comment: The short answers are Yes and No

Comment: @RonTrunk may a better/newer/more expensive AP help somewhat or this is a dead end?

Comment: Save your money.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home/residential networking are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing with such a problem it might be related to **too many access points** transmitting on **the same channel as yours** and overlapping it, causing interferences and signal loss.
My advice would be to download a **wifi analyzer app** as the one in the embedded picture and **check** whether your wifi is transmitting in the **same frequency of other networks**.

You should then configure your wifi access point to transmit over a less saturated channel. In this case I had the same issue, and **the point wasn't in changing the router nor the device**, but instead **to change wifi transmitting channel**.
To know how to do it I'd rather tell you to check your router's manual, but it should be an easy thing to do.

Indeed, checking your environment with a wifi analyzer application would be a good deal to point out the transmission power and reach of your access point. You can even separate 2.4GhZ and 5Ghz access points.

WiFi Monitor, for example, is a very nice app.

[image: A common wifi analyzer app.]

If you have any questions, tell me!

Comment: As I said in the post, I already looked into changing channels. This is a dead end because there is no more room left, all channels are quite saturated. I also separated 2.4 and 5 ghz APs.